# Passing Keycloak Access Token to NextJS?

Tags: openid, keycloak, next.js, express-graphql, hasura

NextJS is a hybrid app and I have created a custom express router that uses keycloak middleware.

I'm trying to pass the bearer token of the userid and pass this token to Hasura so I can lockdown some graphql API, but I don't know how to handle this.

Does anybody have any examples that they can provide that handles this?

I need to figure this out for a Hybrid (SSR React app)

Comment: same question here. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I haven't -- but still trying to fix some backend stuff with keycloak. Have you tried this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AYuhmz-fX4